# jQuery Radio Button Image Swap

Tags: html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I am essentially brand new to coding (html5 forms, CSS3 and now jQuery).

What I am trying to do is have an imageswap (which I have done) attached to a radio button. So what I'm doing is replacing the buttons with images, each with a "pressed" version. However, before even attaching it to a form function/radio button input, I want to find a way so that when I click one button, it switches the other images back to "un-pressed". Essentially so that only one image can be "pressed" at a time.

Right now the code for me pressed images are

```
    $(function() {
        $(".img-swap1").live('click', function() {
            if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap1") {
                this.src = this.src.replace("_U", "_C");
                } else {
                    this.src = this.src.replace("_C","_U");
                }
            $(this).toggleClass("on");
        });

        });
```

I thought about using an if statement to revert all the "_C" (clicked) back to "_U" (unclicked).

Hopefully I've included enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good pattern for solving this problem is to apply the unclicked state to **ALL** your elements, then immediately afterward apply the clicked state to the targeted element.

Also, your if statement `($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap1")` is redundant -- it will always be true because it's the same as the original selector `$(".img-swap1").live('click'...`

Try

```
$(function() {
  $(".img-swap1").live('click', function() {
    $(".img-swap1").removeClass('on').each(function(){
      this.src = this.src.replace("_U", "_C");
    });
    this.src = this.src.replace("_C","_U");
    $(this).addClass("on");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This one worked for me :) For some reason however the U/C were reversed (clicking was putting it into the unclicked state) so I had to reverse the _U and _C in the above. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: Ha! Whoops, that's fair.  I could have guessed that `_U` denoted unclicked.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using "this.src", for example "$(".img-swap1").src" - does that exist?

Comment: `$('.img-swap1').attr('src','newsrc.jpg');`, but if your selector matches multiple images then it will swap the attribute out on *every* image matched.  That's why in the answer code I used `$('.img-swap1').each(function(){ // etc. });`  Because that's an efficient way to perform the operation on each item matched by the selector, but still ensure the code targets them one at a time.  If you really prefer not directly modifying the `src` for some reason, you could use `$(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('_C','_U'));`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly the following may work for you:

```
$(function(){
    $('.img-swap1').live('click', function() {
        $('.img-swap1').removeClass('on').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("_C", "_U")); // reset all radios
        });
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('scr').replace("_U", "_C")); // display pressed version for clicked radio
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `$('.img-swap1').src.replace("_C", "_U")` won't work because jQuery elements don't have a `src` property.  Remember, `$(selector)` always returns an array-like object.

Comment: @DanielMendel Good call! I was following the OP logic and completely spaced.